# How can I implement a long-term connection in WCF, as well as a list of connected clients to the server to which the command can be sent?

Tags: c#, wcf, networking, server, client-server

I want to implement a client-server application and I need the server to contain a list of clients connected to it and in a certain case, for example, when you click on a button, a command is sent to a certain client that it should execute.
Maybe there are other technologies more convenient for this purpose than WCF ?

Comment: The wcf service is not suitable for long-running connections, it just connects every time it is called, and then disconnects when the call ends.